# How do i get distinct value chart from the following table? [Qlik Sense]

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

So the data table I use is like :

| id | status | TimeCompleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Done | 02:04 PM |
| 2 | Done | 02:04 PM |
| 3 | Failed | 02:17 PM |
| 3 | Done | 02:04 PM |

If I try to make a chart for (Count)status(y axis) vs TimeCompleted(x axis), the x axis has duplicate values for `02:04 PM`. I want the graph to show count 3 for `02:04 PM`. How can I do it??

Writing `distinct` in the dimension doesnt help.
I am new to Qlik so need a little help on this problem. Thankyou.

Comment: Can you show your `distinct` code? It should work....

Answer (score 0):

Your dimension should be "TimeCompleted" field. Your expression should be

```
Count( distinct id )
```

That's it.